# How to do I update Assemblies in SQL Server Database Project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2012, .net-assembly, sql-server-data-tools

My goal is to update an assembly within my database project through schema compare with a database that includes an updated version of that assembly.

If I do a Schema Compare in Visual Studio 2015 it shows me that the Assembly is different and that it will be changed if I update. Updating it does not Alter the Assembly but adds a second Assembly.

How do I actually update the assembly?
Or: After adding a second assembly, how do I remove the old assembly and rename the new one without breaking every Function and Procedure referencing it.

PS: I just updated and streamlined this question. Hope that helps.

Comment: If you feel the need to add a "tl;dr" section at the end of your question, then the question itself needs a massive overhaul. Please look at [ask] to get a better understanding.